# vue-i18n: Wrong date format for e.g. Norwegian

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I'm using *vue-i18n* (version 8.24.2) in my app, and everything works as expected except when rendering dates using locale = nb-NO (Norwegian). Expected format: **dd.MM.yyyy**. Actual format: **MM/dd/yyyy**. When switching locale to German, which is using the same date format as Norwegian, correct date format is applied.

This open issue would probably solve my issue:
https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/625

I've spent a couple of hours investigating this issue, but I'm currently stuck, hence any help will be highly appreciated.

My **i18n.ts** (I left out config for languages not related to this issue)

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";

enum Locales {
    NO = "nb-NO"
}

const LOCALES = [
    { value: Locales.NO, caption: "Norsk" }
];

import nb_NO from "./locales/nb-NO.json";

export const messages = {
    [Locales.NO]: nb_NO
};

const defaultLocale = Locales.NO;

const dateTimeFormats = {
    "nb-NO": {
        short: {
            year: "numeric",
            month: "2-digit",
            day: "2-digit",
        },
        long: {
            year: "numeric",
            month: "2-digit",
            day: "2-digit",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit",
            hour12: false,
        },
    },
} as VueI18n.DateTimeFormats;

Vue.use(VueI18n);

// Create VueI18n instance with options
const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: navigator.language.split('-')[0] || process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || defaultLocale,
    fallbackLocale: defaultLocale,
    messages,
    dateTimeFormats: dateTimeFormats,
    silentTranslationWarn: true,
});

const translate = (key: string): string => {
    if (!key) {
        return "";
    }
    return i18n.t(key) as string;
};

export { i18n, translate }; //export above method
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vue-i18n` simply [forwards the date localization to `Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale).format(date)`](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/blob/fdb6bc1/src/index.js#L852).

It seems the result is only incorrect in Chrome as of v92 (*Issue [1233509](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1233509)*). This bug is fixed in Chrome Canary v94.

As a workaround, you can modify the `vue-i18n` instance's `_dateTimeFormatters` to use the Danish (`da`) locale's formatter for `nb-NO`:

```js
const i18n = new VueI18n({/*...*/});
i18n._dateTimeFormatters[Locales.NO + '__short'] =
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('da', dateTimeFormats[Locales.NO].short);
i18n._dateTimeFormatters[Locales.NO + '__long'] =
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('da', dateTimeFormats[Locales.NO].long);
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/workaround-buggy-norwegion-locale-formatter-forked-7dqwp?file=/src/i18n.js:1060-1291)